# How to get a GetElementPtrInst's value after it was define?

Tags: llvm-clang

I used llvm compiled this code,which means I want to send a message if I find a Potential divide-by-zero fault:

```
  int main() {
    int x[3];
    int y;
    x[0] = 0;
    x[1] = tainted_input();
    x[2] = 1;
    y = 4 / x[0]; 
}
```

and compiling result is:

```
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %x = alloca [3 x i32], align 4
  %y = alloca i32, align 4
  %arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i32], [3 x i32]* %x, i64 0, i64 0
  store i32 0, i32* %arrayidx, align 4
  %call = call i32 (...) @tainted_input()
  %arrayidx1 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i32], [3 x i32]* %x, i64 0, i64 1
  store i32 %call, i32* %arrayidx1, align 4
  %arrayidx2 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i32], [3 x i32]* %x, i64 0, i64 2
  store i32 1, i32* %arrayidx2, align 4
  %arrayidx3 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i32], [3 x i32]* %x, i64 0, i64 0
  %0 = load i32, i32* %arrayidx3, align 4
  %div = sdiv i32 4, %0
  store i32 %div, i32* %y, align 4
  ret i32 0
}
```

I find that there is some difference between twice apperance of `x[0]`" ,First time there is:

```
`%arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i32], [3 x i32]* %x, i64 0, i64 0`
```

But next time there is :

```
`%arrayidx3 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i32], [3 x i32]* %x, i64 0, i64 0`
```

So,I don't know how to get `%arrayidx3`'s value and check it if `x[0]` is equal to 0.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

If you can't understand what I want to do,please say it in the comment.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using C/C++, which is a statically compiled language. This means there's a lot of runtime information the compiler hasn't got access to, and these include `zero division` errors. So checking if `x[0]` equals 0 is impossible at compile time as the values have not yet been loaded into actual memory.